# Showing divs in a sequence in a for loop with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing a problem with jquery, I need to show divs in a sequence. All my divs in document have a class of `positioned` . Can't figure out where the bug is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I wrote, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      var items = $('.positioned');
      var delays = 0;

      for ( i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
        items[i].delay(delays).slideDown(200);
        delays = delays + 100;
      }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DARbm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to execute `delay` method on DOM object. Try this:

```
for ( i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
    $(items[i]).delay(delays).slideDown(200);
    delays = delays + 100;
}
```

P.S. I was right. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/DARbm/2/